# Fill Tree Dynamically

Tags: javascript, arrays, tree

I would like to fill a tree dynamically. So I do it like this:

```
         if (TreeTableDataLine.PELEMENT == currPelement) {
        element = {
            element : TreeTableDataLine.ELEMENT,
            TEXT : TreeTableDataLine.TEXT,
        };                                     
        pelement[TreeTableDataLine.PELEMENT][TreeTableDataLine.ELEMENT] = element;
```

Is there a way to fill the path
`pelement[TreeTableDataLine.PELEMENT][TreeTableDataLine.ELEMENT]`
dynamically?

I Tried this:

```
 for (var p = 0; p < pathAr.length; p++) {
            if (p == 0) {
                path = pathAr[p] ;
            } else {
                path = path + "." + pathAr[p];
            }
        }   
pelement[path] = element;
```

But this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Short of using `eval()`, I don't think there's a way to use a string like `y.z` to evaluate `x.y.z`. You need to loop, updating your current reference point as you go.

For example (my second attempt):

```
if (pathAr.length === 1) {
   pelement[pathAr[0]] = element;
   return;
}
var p = pelement[pathAr[0]];
for (var i = 1; i < pathAr.length - 1; i++) {
    p = p[pelement[pathAr[i]];
}
p[pathAr[pathAr.length-1]] = element;
```

Or, in one line:

```
pathAr.slice(0,pathAr.length-1).reduce(function(acc,x) { 
  return acc[x]; }, 
  thing)[pathAr[pathAr.length - 1]] = element
```

Comment: Thanks Steve, it works so far. For now I do it like this.                 switch (pathAr.length) {
   case 1:
    pelement[pathAr[pathAr.length - 1]] = element;
    break;
   case 2:
    pelement[pathAr[pathAr.length - 2]][pathAr[pathAr.length - 1]] = element;
    break;
   case 3:
    pelement[pathAr[pathAr.length - 3]][pathAr[pathAr.length - 2]][pathAr[pathAr.length - 1]] = element;
    break;
   case 4:
    pelement[pathAr[pathAr.length - 4]][pathAr[pathAr.length - 3]][pathAr[pathAr.length - 2]][pathAr[pathAr.length - 1]] = element;
    break;
   default: